# Detect data type java from Data Type oracle in run time

Tags: java, oracle, types, metadata

With using **JAVA** Programming Language, I want to print to console, all Data types which are used in a table of **ORACLE** to their equivalent JAVA Data types; would you help me?

For example:

```
Create table Student (
    STD_ID number (8) primary Key,
    NAME varchar2 (15) not null,
    AGE number (2),
    AVERAGE number (2, 3)
);
```

After running program, the output will be similar below:

1. Integer
2. String
3. Short
4. Double

I reach **oracle** data type via the following code, but to converting Number data type to Integer, Double, Short and other Numeric Data type; I have a problem.

> resultset.getMetaData.getColumnType(columnCount);

Answer (score 1):

> *Why output of numeric field, at table above, show `java.math.BigDecimal`?*

As per `Oracle` documentation on Datatypes and their Java Mappings:

[`NUMBER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/NUMBER.html):

> *The `NUMBER` class provides conversions between the Oracle `Number` (`lnxnum_t`) data type and Java types `byte[], byte, short, integer, long, float, double, String, BigInteger`, and `BigDecimal`.*

[`Understanding Type Maps`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64685/oraext5.htm#1039548):

> *The type map relates a Java class to the SQL type name of an Oracle object. This is a one-to-one mapping that is stored in a hash table as a key-value pair. When you read data from an Oracle object, the JDBC driver considers the type map to determine which Java class to use to materialize the data from the SQL object type. When you write data to an Oracle object, the JDBC driver gets the SQL type name from the Java class by calling the `getSQLTypeName()` method of the SQLData interface. The actual conversion between SQL and Java is handled by the driver.*

This is default behaviour and you can find it on the `getObject` methods *underlying return type*. For a data type of `NUMBER` the return type is `java.math.BigDecimal`.

```
+-----------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| Oracle SQL Type | getObject()            | getOracleObject()      |
|                 | Underlying Return Type | Underlying Return Type |
+-----------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| CHAR            | String                 | oracle.sql.CHAR        |
| VARCHAR2        | String                 | oracle.sql.CHAR        |
| LONG            | String                 | oracle.sql.CHAR        |
| NUMBER          | java.math.BigDecimal   | oracle.sql.NUMBER      |
| RAW             | byte[]                 | oracle.sql.RAW         |
| LONGRAW         | byte[]                 | oracle.sql.RAW         |
| DATE            | java.sql.Timestamp     | oracle.sql.DATE        |
+-----------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

An example of understanding the Java return types on database specific data types are shown in an example on the *Summary* page referred below. Similar example was presented in my previous answer on this post.

**Conclusion**:
Return types are database driver specific. If you want to cast them for your convenience or for any other reason, you can make an explicit call, for example, like `getDouble( columnNumber )` on `NUMBER` data type columns. You may require to handle precision and scale parts, of the returned number value, explicitly.

**Refer to**:

1. [**Oracle's Built-in Data Types**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i54330)
2. [**Summary of getObject() and getOracleObject() Return Types**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64685/oraext3.htm#1010401)
3. [**Valid SQL Datatype-Java Class Mappings**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64685/ref1.htm#1001773)

Answer (score 0):

Once you know you have a numeric column, you can guess the actual type with getPrecision and getScale:

- if getScale() > 0: double
- if getPrecision() > some value: short
- if getPrecision() between some value and some other value: integer
- if getPrecision() > some other value: long.

Answer (score 0):

> *Detect data type java from Data Type oracle in run time*.
>
> *I want to print to console, all Data types which are used in a table of `ORACLE` to their equivalent `JAVA` Data types*

You can call `getColumnClassName` to get the JAVA qualified class match for the data type of any database table column.

**Example**:

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

for( int i=1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++ ) {
    // label if defined else name of column
    String columnLabel = rsmd.getColumnLabel( i ); 

    // data type in database
    String columnType = rsmd.getColumnTypeName( i ); 

    // java equivalent class name
    String columnClassName = rsmd.getColumnClassName( i ); 

    System.out.println( "Column Name : " + columnLabel );
    System.out.println( "Column Type : " + columnType );
    System.out.println( "Column Class: " + columnClassName );

    System.out.println();
} // for count of columns
```

**Output Example**: something like:

```
Column Name : t
Column Type : TIMESTAMP
Column Class: java.sql.Timestamp

Column Name : i
Column Type : INT
Column Class: java.lang.Integer

Column Name : d
Column Type : DATE
Column Class: java.sql.Date

Column Name : e
Column Type : CHAR
Column Class: java.lang.String

Column Name : s
Column Type : VARCHAR
Column Class: java.lang.String
```

**Refer to**:

- [ResultSetMetaData - getColumnClassName( int columnNumber )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnClassName%28int%29)

  - Returns the fully-qualified name of the Java class whose instances are manufactured if the method ResultSet.getObject is called to retrieve a value from the column.

Comment: please see answer 3 carefully .

Comment: *Why output of numeric field, at table above, show java.math.BigDecimal?* You should have added this to your posting rather than adding in an answer. That answer looks like a question but not answer. Better add it to your question.

Comment: @user3184842: I have added another answer on this new question here. Please check.

Comment: dear @user3184842, would you please add link to your answer?

Comment: @user3184842: It is on this post, a [*second answer from me*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22579064/767881).